# Fail to trigger Vuetify form submit using submit button in Jest

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vuetify.js

I'm trying to verify the behavior of a Vue form, based on Vuetify components, using Jest and  Avoriaz.
I can trigger `submit.prevent` on the form, resulting in expected behavior.
But triggering `click` on the submit button does not work.

The component:

```
<template>
  <v-form
    ref="form"
    data-cy="form"
    @submit.prevent="login"
  >
    <v-text-field
      id="email"
      v-model="email"
      label="Email"
      name="email"
      prepend-icon="mdi-at"
      type="text"
      required
      autofocus
      data-cy="email-text"
    />
    <v-btn
      color="primary"
      type="submit"
      data-cy="login-btn"
    >
      Login
    </v-btn>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: 'test@test.com',
    }
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    login: function () {
      console.log('Logging in')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The test setup:

```
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'
import { mount } from 'avoriaz'
import Form from '@/views/Form'

describe('Form', () => {
  const mountFunction = options => {
    return mount(Form, {
      vuetify,
      ...options
    })
  }
```

Where the Vue & Vuetify setup is done in `@/plugins/vuetify`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
})
```

The following test succeeds (thus the mock works):

```
  it('can trigger form directly', () => {
    const login = jest.fn()
    const wrapper = mountFunction()
    wrapper.setData({ 'email': 'test@com' })
    wrapper.setMethods({ login })

    let element = wrapper.first('[data-cy=form]')
    element.trigger('submit.prevent')

    expect(login).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
```

But actually testing the submit button, fails:

```
  it('can trigger form through button', () => {
    const login = jest.fn()
    const wrapper = mountFunction()
    wrapper.setData({ 'email': 'test@test.com' })
    wrapper.setMethods({ login })

    const button = wrapper.first('[type=submit]')
    button.trigger('click')

    expect(login).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
```

Update:
Perhaps some relevant dependencies in `package.json`:

```
{
  ..
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.1",
    "core-js": "^3.4.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.1.3",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.0",
    "vuex": "^3.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ..
    "avoriaz": "^6.3.0",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.5",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

**Update:**
When using test-utils, non Vuetify components (`<form>` and `<btn`), the following test succeeds:

```
const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuetify)
describe('Form', () => {
  const mountFunction = options => {
    return shallowMount(Form, {
      localVue,
      vuetify,
      ...options
    })
  }
  it('can trigger form through button alternative', async () => {
    const login = jest.fn()
    const wrapper = mountFunction({ attachToDocument: true })
    try {
      wrapper.setData({ 'email': 'test@test.com' })
      wrapper.setMethods({ login })

      const button = wrapper.find('[type=submit]')
      expect(button).toBeDefined()
      button.trigger('click')
      await Vue.nextTick()

      expect(login).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    } finally {
      wrapper.destroy()
    }
  })
})
```

Then switching to Vuetify components cause the test to fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, when using Vuetify components (`<v-form>` and `<v-btn>`), there are some key ingredients necessary to make it work:

- Vue **test-utils** instead of avoriaz
- `mount` instead of `shallowMount`
- include `attachToDocument`, which also requires cleaning up afterwards (`wrapper.destroy()`)
- as @Husam Ibrahim also mentioned, need to `async`hronously `await Vue.nextTick()`
- To let the setData have full effect, you might have to extra `await Vue.nextTick()`. In my full code I have form validation (with `:rules` on the input, and `v-model` on the form, and the button's `:disabled` bound to the `v-model` data element. This required two `nextTick()`s

The following works (with `'@/plugins/vuetify'` the same as in the question:

```
import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'
import Vue from 'vue'
import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Form from '@/views/Form'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuetify)

describe('Form', () => {
  const mountFunction = options => {
    return mount(Form, {
      localVue,
      vuetify,
      ...options
    })
  }
  it('can trigger form through button alternative', async () => {
    const login = jest.fn()
    const wrapper = mountFunction({ attachToDocument: true })
    try {
      wrapper.setData({ 'email': 'test@test.com' })
      await Vue.nextTick() # might require multiple
      wrapper.setMethods({ login })

      const button = wrapper.find('[type=submit]')
      button.trigger('click')
      await Vue.nextTick()

      expect(login).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    } finally {
      wrapper.destroy()
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Glad you found the solution :)

Comment: for me It worked just using `mount` instead of `shallowMount`

Answer (score 0):

This could be an async issue. I'd try awaiting `Vue.nextTick()` after triggering the click event and before the assertion ..

```
  it('can trigger form through button', async () => {
    const login = jest.fn()
    const wrapper = mountFunction()
    wrapper.setData({ 'email': 'test@test.com' })
    wrapper.setMethods({ login })

    const button = wrapper.first('[type=submit]')
    button.trigger('click')

    await Vue.nextTick()
    expect(login).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
```

Comment: i had to add `async ` before ` () => { ` to allow using `await`. But still only observe 0 calls of login.

Comment: can there be some non-deterministic behaviour. I changed the test ran it, observed 1 call. then cleaned up, did not get the test to pass. Reverted, and again fails.
My IntelliJ Local History shows that the test succeeded, with your code, but now it fails

Comment: Oops sorry I forgot the async keyword. I'd be surprised if there's any non-deterministic behavior involved. Your code and tests look fully deterministic to me.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately can't get the test to succeed though.